# Issue with associativity of group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Given $G=(1,2)\subset R$ and the operation

$x∗y = \frac{3xy-4x-4y+6}{2xy-3x-3y+5}$

Prove that $(G,∗)$ is an abelian group.

So here's my issue with this. For it to be a group I must prove that: $$(x∗y)∗z=x∗(y∗z)$$, that it has an element **e** for which $$x∗e = e∗x = x$$ and that there is an element x' for which $$x∗x' = e$$ For it to be an *abelian* group I must also prove that $$x∗y=y∗x$$

The problem I'm facing is that I can't seem to simplify the operation, so when I try to prove the associativity of the group I run into very long and troublesome operations. Is there any way around this that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt there's a clever way to do this. I recommend writing out the desired final result in expanded form then doing the computation to see that you get the same thing. For finding the identity and inverses you'll need to solve equations. With a goal in mind I expect the computation will end up not being as bad as you think. (Note commutativity can be shown by showing that the formula is symmetric in $x$ and $y$.)

Comment: Identity, inverse and commutativity weren't a problem really, since the operations are easier and you can simplify some stuff out of them. Associativity is really a hassle though.

Comment: Well, the fraction can be written in a canonical form by clearing denominators. In principle you just churn it out and it should work without having to factor.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the bijection $f\colon (1,2)\to(0,\infty)$, $t\mapsto \frac{2-t}{t-1}$.
Show that $$f(x*y)=f(x)f(y).$$
Conclude that $(G,*)\cong ((0,\infty),\cdot)$.

Comment: Note in particular that this shows associativity, which OP had some trouble with, since then $(x*y)*z = f^{-1}(f(x*y)f(z)) = f^{-1}(f(x)f(y)f(z)) = f^{-1}(f(x)f(y*z)) = x*(y*z)$ (using the associativity of the product in $(0,\infty)$).

Comment: So there IS a clever way.  So much for my prediction.

Comment: @MattSamuel Virtually *all* weird group operations on (subsets of) $\mathbb R$ that are posed as exercise can be solved by exhibiting an isomorphism such as here - but often it is easier to guess. With this in mind, and assuming a Möbius transform as $f$, I noted that subtract one, take reciprocals, subtract one would at least map the interval to the positive reals, i.e., a set that we recognize as a standard group. And - surprise, surpirise - the bijection turns out to be an isomorphism ...

Comment: Besides that, it's a one dimensional connected Lie group. There aren't very many isomorphism classes of those!